# Android move footer up when keyboard is open

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I'm designing a login html page which is loaded into an Android WebView. 
There are two text areas and a "Login" button fixed to the bottom of the page. My problem is that when the person types into the text area; the keyboard pops up and hides the login button.

How can I keep the "Login" button fixed to the bottom of the page but to the top of the keyboard?

I've tried :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

And

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Neither makes a difference.

Comment: So the footer you want to attach to the bottom is part of android view or html webpage??

Comment: The footer is part of the HTML page which is loaded into a full screen android WebView.

Comment: @C0dekid could you expand on your comment a little please.

Comment: @C0dekid I don't see how that would be useful. I'm not trying to move the whole WebView up. I only want the footer to move up inside the WebView.

Comment: Could you show your xml for the webview? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is place your button inside of a `RelativeLayout` and then give it the following attributes:

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

When the screen resizes for the keyboard, the button will be pushed up with the keyboard because `RelativeLayout` adjusts for remaining screen space.

Here's a full working code sample with one button:

```
<!--Parent view-->
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Login Button-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

To fix a an element to the bottom of a page in a web page, you'll need to make the following modifications to the html/css.

```
.login-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Button text

Comment: My button and login page is html in a WebView.

Comment: So do you have access to the html and css for the website?  Otherwise you won't be able to accomplish what you are looking for with any Android commands.

Comment: Yes I do have access to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that you said that the login button was already fixed to the bottom of the screen.  The problem is that the webview window itself isn't resizing when the keyboard appears correct?  If so, is your app set to be fullscreen?

Comment: The WebView is fullscreen and its fine. I just want the footer div to move up inside the WebView when the keyboard opens, I don't want the WebView to move. Sorry, just hard to explain. I think this is more of a html-web problem than Android specific.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late *(5 years)* to answer this question but I just encountered this issue and thought to throw my solution here in case anyone else is still looking for an answer... this is more of a HTML/CSS issue and I solved it by wrapping footer in a container and used the following CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
},

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```